# Unbalanced calls in iOS 8

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

I'm getting the following warning when I present a modal view controller on a navigation controller in iOS 8 at launch.  It works fine on iOS 7.

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UINavigationController.
```

Here's what I'm doing.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   ...
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ...
   [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.modalViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

In iOS 8 I can see the navigation controller for a split second before the modal view is presented.  In iOS 7 I see the modal view controller immediately without the warning.

How to I get the same behavior in iOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rid of the warning, you need to move the code to your first view controllers viewDidAppear. In order to make it look nicer, you might consider doing some tricks. I had the same problem, and I solved it by showing a full screen image of your modal view controller on your first view controller, and hide this image after the modal view controller is presented, e.g. using the method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`

Comment: I can't believe there isn't any other solution, wtf Apple.

Comment: For others that are dealing with this problem, I "fixed" it using this UIView *snapshot = [navigationController.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];